# Macro "oend^[Ores^[" results in new line "end2es". How?

Tags: macro, original-vim

I don't usually have this much trouble debugging issues, but I'm starting to get stumped.

The line doesn't happen when typing the macro out (running it by hand). In fact, it's part of something I recorded.

This doesn't happen when using `vim -u NONE`, which leads me to believe it's due to something in my configuration. I tried to find the issue by deleting my configuration by sections until I found the one that caused it. However, I've moved and deleted **all** run-time loaded vim code (I even moved `/usr/share/vim/` elsewhere) as well as my `~/.viminfo` files and the problem still persists.

I listed all vim related files that vim referred to in system calls:

```
$ strace -fe trace=file vim +q |& grep -Po '[^"]*vim[^"]*(?=")' | sort | uniq
/etc/vimrc
/home/jol/.vim/after/pack/
/home/jol/.vim/after/plugin/
/home/jol/.viminfo
/home/jol/.vim/pack/
/home/jol/.vim/plugin/
/home/jol/.vimrc
/usr/bin/vim
/usr/share/vim
/usr/share/vim/lang/en/LC_MESSAGES/vim.mo
/usr/share/vim/lang/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/vim.mo
/usr/share/vim/lang/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/vim.mo
/usr/share/vim/lang/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/vim.mo
/usr/share/vim/lang/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/vim.mo
/usr/share/vim/lang/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/vim.mo
/usr/share/vim/pack/
/usr/share/vim/plugin/
/usr/share/vim/runtime
/usr/share/vim/vim81
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after/pack/
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after/plugin/
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/pack/
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/plugin/
vim
```

`/etc/vimrc` and `~/.vimrc` exist, but are empty. `~/.viminfo` was generated.

`vim -D` in these circumstances only results in:

```
Entering Debug mode.  Type "cont" to continue.
/etc/vimrc
line 2: End of sourced file
>
```

Any idea for further debugging is appreciated.

EDIT: Hmm. I found something interesting. Apparently, `ofoo^[Obar^[` works perfectly.... `ofoo^[Orar^[` fails by making new line "foo2ar". Running `:abbrev` returns "No abbreviation found".

EDIT 2: Macro `^[Orx^[` deletes 2 letters from the cursor position. I guess it's evaluated like `2x`.

EDIT 3: Macro `^[Otx^[` works like `4x`, and `ofoo^[Otx^[` does indeed print `foo4x` in a new line.

EDIT 4: Macro `ofoo^[Oyx^[` only prints `foo`, but `ofoo^[Oux^[` prints `foo5x`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When vim encounters `^[Or` it interprets it as some kind of special key, for instance a function key.  Which specific one vim thinks it is I'm not sure, but for comparison the `<f3>` key is often `^[OR`.  These escape codes are interpreted in insert mode as keys to allow using function keys and arrow keys.  Ordinarily, it's not an issue because one types more slowly than a macro executes.

One solution is to `set noesckeys` prior to executing the macro.  This option is enabled by vim by default in nocompatible mode.  You can choose to re-enable it after or just keep it always off if you never use special keys in insert mode.

An alternative is to use the `<c-\><c-n>` method of exiting insert mode.  So the macro would look like this:

```
oend^\^NOres^\^N
```

Other control characters could be used, such as `ctrl-@`, which is a no-op in normal mode:

```
oend^[^@Ores^[
```

This will separate the `^[Or` into an unambiguous sequence of commands.

You could also insert a sleep command (`gs`).

```
oend^[gsOres^[
```

`^[gs` is not usually recognized as an escape sequence.
However, this will also cause the macro to sleep for one second.  To get around this, we can remap `gs` to a similar "no operation"

```
nnoremap gs <nop>
```

or,

```
nnoremap <silent> gs :<c-u>sleep 10m<cr>
```

if you would like a shorter sleep.

Comment: Thanks, that's it. `esckeys` (with an "s" at the end, BTW) is set in the normal invocation and unset in `vim -u NONE`. Who knows what sets it. After a few quick greps into my configuration, `/usr/share/vim/` and vim's source, I can't find a plausible place. In any case, it's seems like something I want to keep set. The `<nop>` idea is great.

Comment: typo, thanks.  and vim sets it by itself when running in nocompatible mode, which is default when you use a vimrc but not default when using `vim -u NONE`.  if you want nocompatible mode you would use e.g. `vim -u NONE -N`.

Comment: It just occurred to me that it's odd that something like `^[Orx^[` would cause trouble since `^[` is not done while in insert mode. Maybe that's a bug where these escape sequences are interpreted in normal mode, despite the documentation saying otherwise.

Comment: Nevermind, I get it now. Escape sequences are interpreted in normal mode despite `esckeys` being off.

Comment: @JoL, thanks but I don't recommend using ctrl-c in either mode, because a) it is the interrupt command in normal mode, not a no-op and b) in insert mode it does not trigger InsertLeave, breaking any plugin which relies on that.   In my opinion, `^\^N` is the best alternative way to exit insert mode, so I've added that to the answer.

Comment: Thanks, that seems like an even better solution.

Comment: The issue has been fixed by https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.1.1003.

Comment: @user938271 whoa cool!  The solution was to literally insert `<nop>` into vim's character digestive system